# What does $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] return? Getting strage behavior in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am using Lemp. This code

```
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

$url is set to the value www.mydomain.com/controller/action.

This is what I expected, since it is the url that the code is being executed.

but this

```
$pagina = $i + 1;
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$url .= "/{$pagina}" ;
```

I get $url set to www.mydomain.com.br/1

My controller and action part of url are gone.

Isn't $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] a constant.

I forgot to say my intention, I want to get the current url concanate a value that will be used as route parameter: wwww.mydomain.com.br/controller/action/my_route_parameter_concatenated

Comment: Don't use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] with Laravel. It has very nice URL helpers, check them out.

Comment: I am "upgrading" a site that was originaly written in raw PHP and I was gotten carried away by the already implemented solution. Of course if I have a route and want to pass parameters, link_to_route seems a good way to go.

Comment: There are several possibilities to get URLs in Laravel. My favorite is to use named routes and then `route('foo')`, because that's the most transparent way of linking. The name will stay the same no matter what. My second favorite way is to link by controller's action, like `action('HomeController@welcome');` - this one is awesome too, just a little less flexible on edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use the `url()` helper function for this:

```
url('controller/action/my_route_parameter_concatenated')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-url

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to do this with link_to_route?

Comment: @DiegoAlves Are you using Laravel Collective? If not, what version of Laravel are you using? Either way the short answer is yes. Please can you edit your question and add the routes for the controller?

Comment: Using Laravel 5.2 with Collective.

Answer (score 0):

Answers and commments led me to the right direction. Since was going to use $url to create an anchor tag, I just used   link_to_route('paineldecontrole.anuncios', $pagina, [ $pagina]).

Answer (score -1):

because Yo're using Laravel then maybe use framework power?
http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/07/15/lumen-get-the-full-url-with-the-query-string/
Laravel Request has many more useful tools.